# Pyright shows an error when converting column(int) to int

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, syntax-error, pyright

I can not assign a variable without adding `# type:ignore || Used for pyright (Autocomplete)` or it giving me an error.
Error: `[Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] [E] Argument of type "Column" cannot be assigned to parameter "id" of type "int" in function "__init__"   "Column" is incompatible with "int"`
(Im using SQLAlchemy btw)

Comment: does the program run successfully with the comment used to ignore Pyright's type checker? if so, maybe it's only a mistake of that Microsoft's plugin

Comment: Yeah, it runs fine, but I don't want to add a lot of `# type:ignore` on my code im basically asking if there is an alternative.

Comment: have you tried to put `# type: ignore` as the first line of the file? Since it should work only in its scope, if you put it in the global scope it should make all types in the files ignored

Comment: please, mark the answer as the solution for whoever comes to read this discussion :P thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your extension doesn't work fine with some variable types in the program, you can use `# type: ignore`.

It will work only in its scope, so...

```py
# type: ignore
print(1 + 'x') # -> This won't throw errors

def foo():
  return 2 + "!" # -> Neither this one will throw errors!

print(foo())
```

Instead...

```py
def foo():
  # type: ignore
  return 2 + "!" # -> This one won't throw errors

print(foo())
print(1 + 'x') # -> This one will throw an error!
```

Working only in its scope, `# type: ignore` will have effect on the **entire** script if put in the first lines of the program, in the *global* scope.

Answer (score 2):

I installed the pip package `sqlalchemy-stubs` which helped with this.

https://github.com/dropbox/sqlalchemy-stubs